# cleartool to find more than one type of file

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I would like to describe all batch AND executable files with a cleartool command.
I can do this for one type of file :

```
cleartool find "Z:\PATH" -name *.bat -exec "cleartool describe %%CLEARCASE_PN%%"
```

But I can't find any way to do it for both types of files.
I could duplicate the line, but this is not a good solution because of poor performance.
I have tried surrounding with single or double quotes, with pipe or double pipe, but nothing works (-name "*.bat, *.exe", -name (*.bat || *.exe), etc.). Is there any solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to find *all* files, and test in the exec directive if the extension if the one expected:

```
cleartool find "Z:\PATH" -type f -exec "myscript %%CLEARCASE_PN%%"
```

With `myscript` a script written in the language of your choice, testing the file extension and calling cleartool describe if that extension matches.

Note the `-type f`, to limit the search for the files only (not the folders).

For instance, [in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940412/how-can-i-check-the-extension-of-a-file-using-perl) (and [calling `cleartool` from Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18734933/6309)):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;

$file=$ARGV[0];
my ($dir, $name, $ext) = fileparse($file, @exts);

if ($file ~= /bat|exe) {
  system("cleartool describe $file");
}
```